# Two Icons After Installing A App Flavour

Tags: android

I have a Android app for instance let it be xyz. First i have completed my app after some time i realized that i need to create two different flavor of the app. 1 flavour will be of the main app which i have developed till now my current flavor will be for the driver app and other flavor will be for the user app now i have to create a user flavor and a driver flavor for the driver flavor i have declared the flavor as

```
   main {
        applicationId 'com.example.package.name'
        versionNameSuffix ':Driver'
}
```

main will be the default directory that android studio make in the project while we create a project like this

```
    Project name/app/src/main/java
```

so here i have created main as a flavor and i have another flavor named as user i have created it as

```
    User {
        flavorDimensions "default"
        applicationId 'com.example.package.name.user'
        versionNameSuffix ':User'
}
```

User folder is located at

```
    Project name/app/src/User/java
```

and my default configuration looks like this

```
    defaultConfig {
    applicationId 'com.example.package.name'
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

now what happens is whenever i intall the Driver flavor it installs normaly but whenever i install User flavor of app it install both of the Flavors and shows two icons and Launches different apps on clicking on both the icons suppose if 1st icon placed is of Driver app and 2nd icon is of User app than if we click 1st icon than it launches the Driver app but if i now minimize the app and then click the User icon app even than it launches the Driver app until Driver app is closed

So please help me in solving the problem of installation of multiple flavors of the app when installing a flavor

According to me the reason is that all the flavor must has the default configuration means the code inside main folder so the main folder has a manifest file where there is a activity declared as launcher and User also has a launcher in Manifest file so how can i resolve this problem without moving my files from main.

Comment: How do you install each flavor? Are you installing from Android Studio? Or do you have the apps on Google Play? Or are you using some other method? Also, what version of Android is running on the device which you are installing the apps on?

Comment: I am installing the app from android studio and i am running android 7.1

Comment: Do you start with a fresh device when you install the "User" flavor? Do you uninstall the "Driver" flavor before installing "User"?

Comment: Yes i un-installed both of the flavors before installing and i have done a fresh install

Comment: Can you create a [mcve] which illustrates the behavior?

Comment: can you tell me what what is difference in between product flavor and a creating a separate app because both product flavor and separate project have a different ApplicationId and package name

Comment: I can try to help when you follow the instructions in my previous comment

Comment: Please edit your question to show the AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: I have Two Manifest file one for main Flavor and other for Driver flavor

Comment: Please show both of them.